# How to override a jQuery plugins options in WordPress

Tags: jquery, bxslider

How do i get (programmatically) the current status of my bxSlider? Something like, '**isStarted**', '**isStopped**' is what i need or

`if( $myslider.is('started') )` ...blah ...

but cant find a way of doing this.

thanks

Comment: So is your "slider" on autoplay mode?

Comment: Yes, auto: true and autoControls : true - can't see any methods to achieve this unless your using Ticker mode which i'm not using.